# JavaScript- repeat function to display images

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the following 2 JS function's. Once a user enters a key the image on screen changes. I currently have 8 images which I am working with. How can I make this repeat itself so that the user will have to go through the 8 same images again?

```
function start(){
    if (running==0){
        running = 1;       
        initialTime = Date.now();
    }
    else{
        timer1;
        imagecounter++;
        reset();
    }
}

   function reset(){

    time = 0;

    if(imagecounter > 8){
        document.getElementById("imageDisplay").src ="images/image.png"; 
    }
    else 
    {
        running = 0;
        initialTime = Date.now();
        document.getElementById("imageDisplay").src ="images/image"+imagecounter+".png";
        start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should remove the Java tag if this is JavaScript. Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little difficult to read but I think what you want to do is reset `imagecounter` to 0 so that it starts over.

Change your `reset` function:

```
function reset(){

    time = 0;

    if(imagecounter > 8){
        imagecounter = 0; // <-- reset to 0
        document.getElementById("imageDisplay").src ="images/image.png"; 
    }
    else 
    {
        running = 0;
        initialTime = Date.now();
        document.getElementById("imageDisplay").src ="images/image"+imagecounter+".png";
        start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you increase imagecounter, first check to see if it's greater than or equal to the length of your image array -1. if it is, then set it to 0.